# BTrieve 6.15 in c# or upgrade to PSQL

Tags: btrieve

What's your sugestions about the time effort needed to get access to the old BTrieve 6.15 Database files from C# or is it easier to upgrade the database to PSQL and get access through OLEDB?
It looks to be not so easy to find all the old BTrieve Drivers and to use it in C# - if someone have exerience in the combination of old and new stuff please let me know - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is some google work... Here's what i found:

- possible options: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1681851
- BTreieve classes for .Net - http://www.agtech.co.jp/products/BtrieveClasses/index_e.html ( i didn't search for drivers :) ) - supports v9 - v12